# SQLITE 3 Error - Only on iPhone 5s

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, sqlite

Just shifted to Xcode 5.0 and iOS 7.0 SDK. My whole code works correctly, but while testing the app on all the iPad/Ipod/Iphone family, i noticed that i have the following error when i am using an IPhone 5S ( AKA iPhone Retina - 4 inch 64 bit on the simulator )

```
Problem with prepare statement:  bind or column index out of range
```

The weird thing is that everything works correctly but just on the iPhone 5s i get that error and a bug occurs. The same code worked well on all iPad versions and iPhone versions.
This is the code snippet that caused this problem :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {




    NSIndexPath *indPath3 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:0];
    UITableViewCell *cell3 = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indPath3];
    NSString *cellText3 = cell3.textLabel.text;


    Details22 * vc4 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Details22Iphone"];
    //FavReal* author;
    NSLog(@"This is the showDetailsForIndexPath 2");

    @try{
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"rahme4.sqlite"];
        if(sqlite3_open([writableDBPath UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK) {


            NSString *titleString3 = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Element row number :  %d",indexPath.row];
            NSLog(@"This is the row number chosen %@",titleString3);

               NSString *SearchedItem  = [ cellText3 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'"
                                                                  withString:@"''"];
         //  NSString *formatedSql333 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Select * from Longman where id = '%@'" , iDtoTake ];





            if([SearchedItem isEqualToString:Aa2]){
                formatedSql333 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Select * from Longman where id = '1'" ];
            }


            else{

                formatedSql333 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Select * from Longman where keyword = '%@'" , SearchedItem ];}



            const char *formatedSql3333 = [formatedSql333 UTF8String];

            NSLog(@"This is the SQLite Approriate Query %@",formatedSql333);



            sqlite3_stmt *sqlStatement3;


            NSLog(@"This is the SearchedITem Variable %@" , SearchedItem);


            if(sqlite3_prepare(db, formatedSql3333, -1, &sqlStatement3, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
            {
                NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement:  %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
            }else{

                if(sqlite3_step(sqlStatement3)!=SQLITE_ERROR) {

                    NSLog(@"Entered the While tag");
                //    NSString *SearchedItem = cellText3;
                    NSLog(@"This is the SearchedITem Variable %@" , SearchedItem);


                    Author * author3 = [[Author alloc] init];
                    NSLog(@" Debug 1  ");

                    author3.name = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement3,0)];
                    NSLog(@" Debug 2  ");

                    NSLog(@"This is the author.name in the FavReal %@" , author3.name);


                    //   /         //author3.title = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement3,3)];
                    //  NSLog(@"This is the author.TITLE in the FavReal %@" , author3.title);
                    author3.iDD = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement3, 5)];
                    author3.genre = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement3, 1)];

                    NSLog(@"This is the author.GENRE in the FavReal %@" , author3.genre);
                    NSLog(@"This is the authorName before %@", authorNAme);
                    NSLog(@"This is the authorName2 before %@", authorNAme2);

                    author3.audioAmer = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement3, 7)];
                    author3.audioBrit = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement3, 8)];
                    authorNAme = author3.genre;
                    authorNAme2 = author3.name;
                    AmericanAudio = author3.audioAmer;
                    BritishAudio = author3.audioBrit;

                    iDtoTake = author3.iDD;
               //     NSLog(@"This is the authorName after %@", authorNAme);
               //     NSLog(@"This is the authorName2 after %@", authorNAme2);
                             NSLog(@"This is the idToTake in FavrealIphone %@", iDtoTake);

                    //  author3 = [theFav objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

                    // [theFav addObject:author3];

             //       NSLog(@"Before the break");
              //      NSLog(@"Before the animation part");
                    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc4 animated:true];
              //      NSLog(@"Passed the should animate part");
                    // sqlite3_close(db2);
                    //break;
                    NSLog(@"After the break");
                    sqlite3_finalize(sqlStatement3);

                }

            }
        }

        // sqlite3_close(db2);
    }



    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement:  %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    }


    @finally {

        NSLog(@"The database should NOT be closed here");



    }




}
```

While using the debugger, i noticed that the debugger arrives at the following line

```
author3.audioAmer = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement3, 7)];
                author3.audioBrit = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement3, 8)];
```

And if i comment it, the bug disappears, but i need it , so anyone faced any similar problem ? 
Thank you

Comment: What happens if you change `SELECT * FROM ...` to `SELECT col1, ... coln FROM ...` (which is a good idea anyway)?

Comment: It's probably that one or both of those two lines you are commenting out are actually throwing an NSException that you are not expecting and it is being caught and printed by the @catch which assumes only the prepare call can throw an error. Enable an exception breakpoint and step over each of those lines and see if either of them throws an exception.